# How to apply type search feature to ng-boostrap dropdown?

Tags: javascript, css, angular, ng-bootstrap

I've added to my ASP.NET MVC with Angular 4 app [ng-bootstrap dropdown.](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/dropdown/examples)
Unfortunately I found that the dropdown is missing type search feature. 
If I open dropdown, the are three items: One, Two, Three. I want to have the option of typing "Two" and the item would be pre-selected so I could then press Enter to select that item.

I suspect the problem with ng-bootstrap dropdown is that it is using buttons not list items like standard dropdowns do. 
Does anyone know whether there is an easy way to add this feature to the dropdown? Or perhaps I should use some other dropdown?

Thanks any attempt to help with that.

Comment: Seems like you're trying to combine the behaviour of something like typeahead with a basic dropdown. How about making the first dropdown item an input field and then going from there?

Comment: I've tried input field and works in the same way as button.